# Image as check box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 images. 
What i want to do is to make it clickable and selectable.
If i select the first one the other should not be selected.

and if i click a button it should print the vaalue of the selected image on `<p>` tag

This is the code which i got after searching a lot :

```js
$('#img1').click(function() {
  var a = $('#img1');
  //A if else condition should be here to know wheather it already contain the class
  a.addClass('clicked')
})
$('#img2').click(function() {
  var a = $('#img2');
  //A if else condition should be here to know wheather it already contain the class
  a.addClass('clicked')
})
$('button').click(function() {
  var a = $('#img1').val();
  var b = $('#img2').val();
  $('p').html(/*The value of the selected image*/)
})
```

```css
.clicked {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px grey;
}
img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" width="100px" height="100px" id="img1" value="noo">
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar2.png" width="100px" height="100px" id="img2" value="yes"><br>
<button>
Copy
</button>
<p>

</p>
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atfqhwzo/)
Thanks

Comment: w3schools taught you to have `px` inside `width` and `height` attribute? No. That's incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#img1').click(function() {
var a = $('#img1');
 $('#img2').removeClass('clicked');
 //A if else condition should be here to know wheather it already contain the class
  a.addClass('clicked')
})
 $('#img2').click(function() {
    var a = $('#img2');
  $('#img1').removeClass('clicked');
//A if else condition should be here to know wheather it already contain the class
 a.addClass('clicked')
})
$('button').click(function() {
$('p').html($('.clicked').attr('value'))
})
```

```css
.clicked {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px grey;
}
img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" width="100px" height="100px" id="img1" value="noo">
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar2.png" width="100px" height="100px" id="img2" value="yes"><br>
<button>
Copy
</button>
<p>

</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have updated your js use `$('#img1').removeClass('clicked');` on click functions

```
$('#img1').click(function() {
var a = $('#img1');
 $('#img2').removeClass('clicked');
 //A if else condition should be here to know wheather it already contain the class
  a.addClass('clicked')
})
 $('#img2').click(function() {
    var a = $('#img2');
  $('#img1').removeClass('clicked');
//A if else condition should be here to know wheather it already contain the class
 a.addClass('clicked')
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use this code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('img').click(function() {
    $('img').removeClass('clicked');
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
})
$('button').click(function() {
    var value = $('.clicked').attr("value");
  $('p').html(value);
})
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('img').click(function() {
  $('img').removeClass('clicked')
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
  console.log($(this).attr('data-value'))
})
$('button').click(function() {
  $('p').html($('img.clicked').attr('data-value'))
})
```

```css
.clicked {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px grey;
}
img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" width="100px" height="100px" id="img1" data-value="noo">
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar2.png" width="100px" height="100px" id="img2" data-value="yes"><br>
<button>
Copy
</button>
<p>

</p>
```

1. change attr value to data-attr since it is not a valid attr
2. use img tag then detect the click element with this context
3. the use the data-attr to show the value

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
$('#img1').click(function() {
  resetClick();
  var a = $('#img1');
  //A if else condition should be here to know wheather it already contain the class
  a.addClass('clicked')
})
$('#img2').click(function() {
  resetClick();
  var a = $('#img2');
  //A if else condition should be here to know wheather it already contain the class
  a.addClass('clicked')
})
function resetClick(){
  $('#img1').removeClass('clicked');
  $('#img2').removeClass('clicked');
}
$('button').click(function() {
   $('p').html( $('img.clicked').attr('value'));  
})
```

```css
.clicked {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px grey;
}
img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png" width="100px" height="100px" id="img1" value="noo">
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar2.png" width="100px" height="100px" id="img2" value="yes"><br>
<button>
Copy
</button>
<p>

</p>
```